# task zip for Gradle 5 Could not set unknown property ‘archiveBaseName’

Tags: gradle

The `baseName` property has been deprecated and documentation states [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip:baseName) that:

> Note: This property has been replaced by archiveBaseName.

Yet, when I try to set this property in a zip task I got the error: `Could not set unknown property ‘archiveBaseName’`

I am using Gradle wrapper with version 5.4.1 and this is the configuration that I am using:

```
task packageNpmApp(type: Zip) {
    dependsOn npm_run_build
    archiveBaseName 'npm-app'
...
```

The build succeeds when I use the deprecated property `baseName` rather than `archiveBaseName`. But I would like to use the most recent API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in their example [working with files](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/working_with_files.html) , the usage is

```
task packageNpmApp(type: Zip) {
  ..
  archiveBaseName = 'npm-app'
  ..
```

---

Note that on the Javadocs, `archiveBaseName` is a Property, see [getArchiveBaseName](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/AbstractArchiveTask.html#getArchiveBaseName--), and (in theory?..I am no big groovy expert) that assignment should be equivalent to `getArchiveBaseName().set('npm-app')`

Answer (score 2):

The property you should use is  **archivesBaseName** inside the defined project or task,

e.g.

```
task packageNpmApp(type: Zip) 
  {
  archivesBaseName = "$project.name"
  }
```